# Android : Switching between Activities that render OpenGL ES 2.0 : Perspective gets corrupted

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview, perspectivecamera

I have a app that has 2 main activities that both render a OpenGL ES 2.0 Surface/renderer/context

When I go from 1 activity to the next, everything renders fine on the new activity, the **onPause** is called on the first activity which pauses the surface.

When I return to the first activity by calling finish on the second activity, the rendered view perspective goes all weird,  its like its been zoomed out.

The **onSurfaceCreated** is called, and the **onSurfacedChanged** is called twice on the first activity (when returning).

```
@Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {

        // Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_LEQUAL);
        GLES20.glDepthMask(true);

        mCamera = new Camera(Camera.PLAYER_IPD, Camera.PLAYER_EYE_HEIGHT, Camera.CAMERA_FOV, 1);
        mCamera.mPosZ = 10;
        mIPD = mCamera.getIPD();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {

        screenWidth = width;
        screenHeight = height;

        mHalfWidth = screenWidth / 2;
        mHeight = screenHeight;

        mRatio = (float) mHalfWidth / height;
        mCamera.setFOV(mCamera.getFOV(), mRatio);
        frameCheckTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000;

        float ratio = (float) width / height;

        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1.0f, 10);
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -1.0000001f, 0.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        mGLView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mGLView.onResume();
    }
```

**Before**
[image: Before]

**After**
[image: After]

Comment: You have the following line of code that may be the problem: `mCamera.setFOV(mCamera.getFOV(), mRatio);` - without setting the FOV beforehand, you get it it from the camera object and set it again alongside with `mRatio`. I guess that may be the cause for the gradual perspective change when that line gets called over and over again.

Comment: Sadly that did not work, but thanks for trying :)

Comment: Print the values you're using to configure the camera to the log file (e.g. that `setFOV` call).  Are they changing every time?  If so, why?